# How to get my java program to run again if the user decides to?

Tags: java, exit

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to continue the program?",null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
    System.exit(0);
}
if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    // What do i put here to run my program again?
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend working with GUIs before you learn about all the language basics, such as while loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `main()` method just like any other method but consider that you have to reset all values and close any open Frames